# Execute Python script via Apache

Tags: python, apache

I'm using Python 3.4 and Apache/2.4.6

Apache:

```
$ tail /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

ScriptAlias /python/ /var/www/python/
<Directory "/var/www/python">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
    AddHandler default-handler .html .htm
</Directory>
```

CGI script:

```
$ ls -ld /var/www/python
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 17 17:30 /var/www/python/
$ ls -ld /var/www/python/my_script.py 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 106 May 17 17:29 /var/www/python/my_script.py
```

Yet, when I do:

```
$ curl http://localhost/python/my_script.py
```

I get:

```
#!/opt/python/bin/python
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()
print ("""<H1>Hello, world!</H1>""")
```

instead of my desired HTML output.

Comment: You probably have, but just checking: did you tell Apache to reload the configuration file after you edited it?

Comment: Good question, yes I did.